# how to determine if any column has a particular value

Tags: python, string, pandas, row

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID           Column1            Column2             Column3
1            cats                 dog                bird
2            dog                 elephant           tiger
3            leopard             monkey             cat
```

I'd like to create a new column that indicates whether `cat` is present in that row, as part of a string, so that the dataframe looks like this:

```
   ID           Column1            Column2             Column3  Column4
    1            cats                 dog                bird      Yes
    2            dog                 elephant           tiger     No
    3            leopard             monkey             cat       Yes
```

I would like to do this without assessing each column individually, because in the real data set there are a lot of columns.

Comment: `(df=='cat').any(1)
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick for you:

```
df['Column4'] = np.where((df.astype(np.object)=='cat').any(1), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Working example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'Column1': ['cat', 'dog', 'leopard'], 'Column2': ['dog', 'elephant', 'monkey'], 'Column3': ['bird', 'tiger', 'cat']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
   Column1   Column2 Column3  ID
0      cat       dog    bird   1
1      dog  elephant   tiger   2
2  leopard    monkey     cat   3
>>> df['Column4'] = np.where((df.astype(np.object)=='cat').any(1), 'Yes', 'No')
>>> df
   Column1   Column2 Column3  ID Column4
0      cat       dog    bird   1     Yes
1      dog  elephant   tiger   2      No
2  leopard    monkey     cat   3     Yes
```

**EDIT:** 
In case you want to check if any of the columns *contains* a particular string you can use the following:

```
df['Column4'] = df.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('cat', case=False).any(), axis=1)
```